# Config for 'Cache' in settings.CACHES missing

Tags: django, caching, memcached, django-cache

I have configured cache in settings.py in my Django project as follows:

```
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ALIAS = 'Cache'
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS = 60
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX = ''
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
    }
}
```

Cache service is running after I typed: `$ memcached -p 11211 &`

But when I try to run server, the following error shows up:
`django.core.cache.backends.base.InvalidCacheBackendError: Could not find config for 'Cache' in settings.CACHES`

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ALIAS` setting tells the django middleware which cache to use: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#cache-middleware-alias

Here it is set to `'Cache'` but there is no cache of that name in your `CACHES` setting. You probably don't want a different alias and should just use the default of `'default'` so just remove that setting.